# Android Kotlin - get value from multidimensional / nested JSON

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

On the server I create this json with PHP:

```
    $array = array();    
    $array['stuff'] = "yeee";
    $array['bla'] = "ok";
    
    $serverScaling = array();
    $serverScaling["0"] = "okOne";
    $serverScaling["1"] = "okTwo";
    $serverScaling["2"] = "okThree";
    
    $array['serverScaling'] = $serverScaling;
    
    echo json_encode($array);
```

how can I get `okTwo`?

In volley response I tried:

```
val response = JSONObject(it)

val serverScaling = JSONObject(response.getString("serverScaling"))
Log.d(tagg, "hmm: " + serverScaling.getString("1"))
```

and also:

```
val response = JSONObject(it)

val serverScaling = response.getJSONObject("serverScaling")
Log.d(tagg, "hmm: " + serverScaling.getString("1"))
```

How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

serverScaling is a jsonArray so fetch it as an array not an object like below :

```
 val response = JSONObject(it)

 val serverScaling = response.getJSONArray("serverScaling")
 Log.d(tagg, "hmm: " + serverScaling.getString("1"))
```